# ELK: logstash dashboard

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I am playing with the ELK module and other "beats". I realized there are cool default dashboards for Metricbeats and Heartbeat. But I couldn't find anything about logstash.
So I was wondering: Is there an example of a dashboard for Logstash in Kibana?

Answer (score 0):

Logstash actually doesn't have any dashboard with it. It doest work as Heartbeat or Metricbeats on one task. 
Logstash just powerful instrument to capture and modify data on the fly. It has many different plug-ins for it and can be used regardless elastic for example to capture data, parce it, create fields from raw data and send it to back-end which could be elastic, hive, sql or just e-mail. 
So it doesn't, but you can create your own dashboard from data which coming from logstash